# How do you fix Android Studio auto-complete with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am setting the Android Studio to use Firebase, but after the settings the Android Studio auto-complete does not show for example (DatabaseReference). I am setting everything as Google suggests.What is wrong?

See the image:

Firebase Configuration

[image]

Android Studio

[image]

My Project Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

My App Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Close Android studio then go to the folder where android studio is located Or you can go to the

drive C -> users -> find .gradle file and do below things

Find .gradle file -> In .gradle folder delete caches folder then restart android studio sync your files with gradle.